# How to draw complex round border with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I want to draw complex round border and round rectangle with shadow , but I can't find how to.
I want to draw a box border naturally, just like browser CSS border elements. What should I do?

like div element in browser with this CSS.

```css
border-radius: 10% 30% 50% 70%;
border-left: 4px solid #000;
border-top: 10px solid #ff0;
border-right:  3px solid #F01;
border-bottom:  9px solid #0f0;
box-shadow: 10px 10px gray;
```

[image]

How to draw the border path, I don't know how to smoothly change the thickness and color of the path,
Drawing with a combination of DrawLine and DrawArc does not change the thickness smoothly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I do know how to obtain the smooth border-width transition but not the color transition.
By using an outer and inner rrect:

```
void draw(SkCanvas* canvas) {
  SkRRect content_rrect;
  SkRRect border_rrect;

  float rtopleft = 80.0f, rtopright = 240.0f, rbottomright = 400.0f,
        rbottomleft = 540.0f;
  int w = 600, h = 450;
  int btop = 40, bbottom = 36, bleft = 16, bright = 12;
  int xo = 100, yo = 100;
  char const str[] = "This is a box with rounded corners";

  const SkVector content_radii[] = {SkVector::Make(rtopleft, rtopleft),
                                    SkVector::Make(rtopright, rtopright),
                                    SkVector::Make(rbottomright, rbottomright),
                                    SkVector::Make(rbottomleft, rbottomleft)};

  const SkVector border_radii[] = {
      SkVector::Make(rtopleft + bleft, rtopleft + btop),
      SkVector::Make(rtopright + bright, rtopright + btop),
      SkVector::Make(rbottomright + bright, rbottomright + bbottom),
      SkVector::Make(rbottomleft + bleft, rbottomleft + bbottom)};

  content_rrect.setRectRadii(SkRect::MakeXYWH(xo + bleft, yo + btop, w, h),
                             content_radii);
  border_rrect.setRectRadii(
      SkRect::MakeXYWH(xo + 0, yo + 0, w + bleft + bright, h + btop + bbottom),
      border_radii);

  SkPaint paint;
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
  canvas->drawDRRect(border_rrect, content_rrect, paint);

  SkPaint text_paint;
  text_paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  text_paint.setColor(0xFF000000);
  SkFont font;
  font.setSize(25);
  // text positioning is just a speculation as it'd be out of scope to calculate
  // it for this example
  canvas->drawSimpleText(str, strlen(str), SkTextEncoding::kUTF8, xo + w / 4,
                         yo + h / 2, font, text_paint);
}
```

This is written using the C++ Skia API and should be easy to translate to C#.

Hope this helps.

For the color transition effects, you could try some of the Filters or Effects (i.e. **DashPathEffect**, **1DPathEffect**, **2DPathEffect**).

PS: I couldn't get **DashPathEffect** (4 **DashPathEffect**s {for each border} with 3 off and 1 on interval each) to work for it because the results on CPU were different from GPU.

[View Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMZtV.png)